# How do I get URL of upload file into script

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, upload, raphael

Upon upload completion, my newly uploaded file has the URL of

```
    <div id="uploaded-file">

    <img src="http://path-to-my-file.jpg" />

    </div>
```

How do I get the URL of that uploaded file into my script?

```
    <script>
    script stuff.use this.etc
    ('http://path-to-my-file.jpg')
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

EDIT:

I used:

```
    <script>
    var myurl = document.getElementById("uploaded-file").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;   

    </script>
```

then replace the hardcoded url:

```
    Layer_3.mousedown(function() { this.animate({ fill:
    'url("http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4067/4584507098_b887327eae.jpg")' }, 600); });
```

with

```
    Layer_3.mousedown(function() { this.animate({ fill: 'url(' + myurl + ')' }, 600); });
```

**[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rednevednav/C9aDm/)**

Comment: can you explain, which script you are talking about, i have a admin panel from where user uploads the images, those images are stored in a folder on my server, we retrieve those images as per the id's where we require.

Comment: Actually, I am wanting to pull that URL from user's uploaded image and use a fill attr for svg path. Obviously the uploaded file will change each time...I need to be able to call whatever file is uploaded no matter what it is. Will hopefully use as a drag and drop function....uploaded image is dragged to desired area of svg image and dropped to fill. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @rednevednav, you are still not clear. Can you please post your javscript code. Are you storing the uploaded file on the server? If yes, you must already be knowing the physical path. Are you looking for an answer to convert physical path to an URL?

Comment: Yes, storing uploaded file on the server... here is [JSFiddle: link](http://jsfiddle.net/rednevednav/C9aDm/) ....scroll to bottom of script pane...hard coded img in there....you can click on image and see.....I need to be able to have a generic fill for whatever is uploaded ....I can work the rest of it out....just cant get the dang url in the script....brain-flatulence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<script>
    var myurl = document.getElementById("uploaded-file").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;   
    alert(myurl);
</script>
```

Comment: I quite obviously new here...is there anything else I should do to 'close' this out? Or post in your favor, etc?

Comment: You've accepted the answer, which is great and effectively 'closes' the question, although it remains available to view and edit so that other people can refer to it, and things may change over time.  If you'd like to post in my (or any-one's) favour, you can 'upvote' (or downvote) any answer using the up and down arrows to the left of the post.  The big numeral between the arrows indicates how many up or down votes it has received.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery (though you could use vanilla JS instead)...

```
uploadedImg = $('#uploaded-file').find('img');
imgSrc = uploadedImg.attr('src');
```

You then have the src as a variable...

(That's all I can give you without more information. There are probably better ways of doing this, but your initial problem isn't really clear...)

Comment: `Layer_3.mousedown(function() {
        this.animate({
            fill: 'url("http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4067/4584507098_b887327eae.jpg")'
        }, 600);
    });`

Comment: Layer_3.mousedown(function() {
        uploadedImg = $('#uploaded-file').find('img');
        imgSrc = uploadedImg.attr('src'); 
        this.animate({ fill: 'url(imgSrc)' }, 600);
    });